Unable to create a resource group as well as resource in same arm template
I want to create a resource group and after that create NSG in same resource group.
ARM template -
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "deployment-rg",
      "location": "easatus",
      "subscriptionId": "[parameters('subscriptionId')]",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
              "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
              "name": "demo-test",
              "location": "eastus",
              "properties": {}
            }
          ],
          "outputs": {}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "deployment-nsg",
      "comments": "test vnet",
      "resourceGroup": "demo-test",
      "dependsOn": [
        "['deployment-rg']"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
              "name": "nsg",
              "location": "eastus",
              "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                  {
                    "name": "AllowAll",
                    "properties": {
                      "priority": 100,
                      "protocol": "*",
                      "sourcePortRange": "*",
                      "destinationPortRange": "4489",
                      "sourceAddressPrefix": "Gateway",
                      "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                      "access": "Allow",
                      "direction": "Inbound",
                      "sourcePortRanges": [],
                      "destinationPortRanges": [],
                      "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                      "destinationAddressPrefixes": [],
                      "description": "more info."
                    }
                  }                  
                ]
              },
              "tags": {
                "resourceType": "Demo NSG",
                "clusterName": "Apps Demo"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

I have used depends on as well in NSG still getting below error -

Error: Code=ResourceGroupNotFound; Message=Resource group
'demo-test' could not be found.

Any idea what is wrong here.

Different scope of deployment can't be config 'dependson'. Creating a new resource group should be in the scope of 'subscription' level, nsg in 'resource group' level. so when you sample code runs, 'nsg' resource and 'resource group' resource are creating simultaneously, 'nsg' can't find his containered resource group, because is in creating, so the error shows resource group not found. -> you can run twice of you code, it works. but it's just a trick.

It is not possible to deploy a resource group from a resource group ARM template (schema https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#). You must use a subscription scoped ARM template (schema https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#).
This template uses a nested template to then create a deployment scoped to the resource group which deploys the NSG.
Here is an updated ARM template which you should deploy with the az deployment sub create Azure CLI command:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "demo-test",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "deployment-nsg",
            "comments": "test vnet",
            "resourceGroup": "demo-test",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', 'demo-test')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                            "name": "nsg",
                            "location": "eastus",
                            "properties": {
                                "securityRules": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "AllowAll",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "priority": 100,
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "4489",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "10.0.3.0/27", // Replace this with the CIDR range of your GatewaySubnet
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "direction": "Inbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "description": "more info."
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "tags": {
                                "resourceType": "Demo NSG",
                                "clusterName": "Apps Demo"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}

Note that the sourceAddressPrefix on your NSG (Gateway) was erroring for me. I replaced it with a fictitious CIDR range (10.0.3.0/27), but you'll want to replace this with the CIDR range of your Gateway subnet.

im getting below error still as in my same template im creating logic apps also. is it because of that?
Error: Code=ResourceGroupNotFound; Message=Resource group 'demo-test' could not be found.

Update your post to include the ARM template with the logic app and I'll see if I can see what's wrong with it.

ok let me try to update it , I have logic apps , role assignment for cosmos , event grid , storage account its a very big scrip :(
let me add type of each resource section so that it may help.
